# Unzipping to general file share is slow on azure shared disk. Clustered windows server 2019

Tags: azure, network-share, windows-server-2019, file-sharing, failovercluster

I have a file share server running on an azure VM cluster.

Copying already existing files to the file share gets really good speed.  Averaging about 60 MBps.  So if I copy a file from a local machine to the file share I get good performance.

What I've noticed as that when writing a stream of data to the share it runs at only 3-8MBps.

So for instance running an unzip from a local machine and extracting to the file share runs quite a bit slower.  Additionally we have an SSIS package that writes a large text file to the share and that runs slow as well.

I've followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/file-server/smb-file-server) and changed many of the parameters but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The disk on the file server is named F:\ if I unzip the file directly to F it runs very quickly so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the disk itself.  It's only when I try to go through the fileshare that I get issues.

Any help would be appreciated and if there is any other information you need to help me troubleshoot please let me know.

This is a general file share but there is also an SOFS file share on the same server (different disk).

Comment: Being this is an Azure VM, is there a VPN or anything between the client and the server?

Comment: For the purpose my testing I've been running this from the server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to find the issue.  We needed to disable continuous availability for the share.

Once we did that I saw the unzip go from 3MBps to 88MBps.